# GCE instance terminated without detail or clarification

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

We got a weird error event last night where a GCE VM instance got terminated by the system for reasons that are unclear. Is there any way to identify why a running instance got terminated?

Portion of the REST response from the GCE service:

```
{
  "kind": "compute#operation",
  "operationType": "compute.instances.guestTerminate",
  "status": "DONE",
  "statusMessage": "Instance terminated by guest OS shutdown.",
  "user": "system",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it appears that your instance's guest OS itself was the one which requested to shutdown / halt so the instance was terminated as a result. This could be due to any number of reasons, e.g., someone ran a command such as `shutdown -h now` inside the VM.

The record of what happened in this case may be left on the instance's persistent disk; however, if the VM had the setting enabled for automatically deleting the boot disk on VM instance termination, it's likely gone at this time.