# Google Cloud Platform - VM instances terminate automatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform

VM instances are automatically terminated when idle, log details of vm instance is provided below. Is there is any pre-set idle time for VM instances in GCP before they are terminated automatically?

```
compute.instances.guestTerminate
{"actor":{"user":"system"}

{
 insertId:  "1cul1b9g4an2h44"  
 jsonPayload: {
  actor: {
   user:  "system"    
  }
  event_subtype:  "compute.instances.guestTerminate"   
  event_timestamp_us:  "1516163427866891"   
  event_type:  "GCE_OPERATION_DONE"   
  operation: {

  }
  resource: {

  }
  trace_id:  "systemevent-1516163412743-562f14da3546f-72606fb9-e7cfbf6e"   
  version:  "1.2"   
 }
 labels: {

 }
```

191721/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Factivity_log"
     receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-17T04:30:27.942931382Z"
     resource: {
      labels: {

```
  }
  type:  "gce_instance"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 timestamp:  "2018-01-17T04:30:27.866891Z"  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Compute Engine has no pre-set idle time for VM instances. However, if your instance is [Preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible), Compute Engine might terminate it due to system events, and this probability is generally low. In this case, if you do not have a shutdown script, it will simulate an “ACPI Power Off” signal, and log `"operationType": "stop"`.

On the other hand,  if your instance is configured on maintenance events to [live migrate](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) with automatic restart, then “if a hardware fails completely or otherwise prevents live migration, the VM crashes and restarts automatically and a hostError (or `compute.instances.hostError`, and `compute.instances.automaticRestart` ), is logged.”

In your case, according to the first two lines in the log above, it seems that it was terminated (shut down) by the guest OS itself, and could be user initiated. I simulated the same exact log by running:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

To troubleshoot, you may have to check your VM logs. I found a similar report and answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685901/gce-instance-terminated-without-detail-or-clarification).

On another note, and for security reasons, it’s best to redact your project and resource information from the log above.

Comment: I faced the issue again but unsure why this is happening, when VM is idle for certain time these instances turn off automatically. Per logs it shows "guest terminate" but I never ran a shutdown command on the instance.

Comment: @Vegapatel , have you tried to check the logs on the VM instance itself?  I am suspecting that it could be an application or a script that triggered the shutdown from within the VM instance.