# GCP compute engine instance terminates randomly

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP compute engine instance terminates randomly.
Following details are captured in the logs

```
actor: {
  user: "system"    
}
event_subtype: "compute.instances.guestTerminate"   
event_timestamp_us: "1585816685801747"   
event_type: "GCE_OPERATION_DONE"   
info: [
 0: {
    code: "STATUS_MESSAGE"     
    detail_message: "Instance terminated by guest OS shutdown."     
 }
]
```

Comment: Have a look at the error message `"Instance terminated by guest OS shutdown."` - this issue directly related to your OS.  1. Which OS do you use on your VM? 2. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> go to section **`Logs`** click on `Serial port 1 (console)` and look for some errors there and/or share log at [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/). 3. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> go to section **`Logs`** click on `Stackdriver Logging` and check there as well.

Comment: This means it is the OS itself that requested the shutdown, or someone who has access to the machine specifically told it to shut down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this [GCE instance terminated without detail or clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685901/gce-instance-terminated-without-detail-or-clarification)

You may have configured the Compute Engine to terminate on shutdown.

Comment: Thank you. But there is no such configuration; and it gets terminated frequently even after seconds I start it manually.

Comment: May I know how you started the instance?

Comment: Using gcp console

Comment: I mean can you link me to the steps you followed? Like what commands you used?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, your VM's OS initiated the shutdown because of the method `compute.instances.guestTerminate`.

Review the Cloud Audit Logs and look for the `principalEmail` field to identify the user or system that triggered the shutdown.